# How to create an hexagonal iFrame for a Google Maps embed?

Tags: google-maps, iframe, maps

I'm looking for a way to create an hexagonal iFrame in order to get a Map from Google inside.
Just like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6CbK.png

I guess I need a way to apply style on the border of the iFrame but I can't find the way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made something here. I think it works for you (if i understand well your needs) ;)

CSS3 is very powerful.

In fact you just have to do 3 `<div>` and rotate them. Then, insert your Google `<div>` and `overflow:hidden` the 3 `<div>` containers.

```
<div class="hexagon hexagon2">
    <div class="hexagon-in1">
        <div class="hexagon-in2">
            <div id="map" style="width:200px;height:300px;margin-top:80px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Complete code - JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wn9nhbLu/2)

Best regards.

Comment: Happy to ear that. Put the green V on m'y answer to close the question ;) thx